# Use UnsafeProjection to convert row to Person Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I write a simple test case that want to convert `InternalRow(UTF8String.fromString("tom"), 1)` to an UnsafeRow that has only one field(type is `ObjectType(classOf[Person])`)

```
  test("SparkTest UnsafeProjection") {
    val row = InternalRow(UTF8String.fromString("tom"), 1)
    val encoder = ExpressionEncoder[Person].resolveAndBind()
    val proj = UnsafeProjection.create(Seq(encoder.deserializer))
    val proj_row = proj(row)
    val p = proj_row.get(0, ObjectType(classOf[Person])).asInstanceOf[Person]
    println(p.name)
    println(p.age)
  }
```

When I run it, an exception throws,but I don't know how to fix to make

```
Unsupported data type ObjectType(class org.apache.spark.sql.Person)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unsupported data type ObjectType(class org.apache.spark.sql.Person)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedUnsafeProjection$.generateFieldWriter(InterpretedUnsafeProjection.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedUnsafeProjection$.$anonfun$generateStructWriter$1(InterpretedUnsafeProjection.scala:114)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
```